# This action will actually increase or decrease a webpage performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created this piece of code to increase my webpage performance.
If `autoplay.v.mystart` is true, the  sliding and animations of 2 slideshows will not be played,I made condition on it. My aim is to stop the animations while user is scrolling and reactivate it while user stopped scrolling, I think it will reduce a webpage load, to make a webpage scroll smoother, as I listened to people say stop unused animations or hide things that's unused. However, I see it didn't go smoother, but a bit more laggy. Is it using scroll event listener and timer/cleartimeout will take up a lot of resources too? What is the best way to accomplish my aim , to reduce my webpage load? I am thinking should I remove this code?That will be a waste,I can't decide

```
var saviour = {
    '$mywrapper' : $('#wrapper'),
    'mychecked':false,
    run : function(){
        var wrapper_timer;
        saviour.$mywrapper.scroll(function(){
            if(saviour.mychecked==false){
                saviour.mychecked = true;
                autoplay.v.mystart = false;
                clearTimeout(wrapper_timer);
                setTimeout(function(){saviour.mychecked=false},1000);
                wrapper_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                autoplay.v.mystart = true;
                console.log('autoplay restart')
                },4000);
                console.log('check');
            }
        });
    }
}
saviour.run();
```

Comment: Why re-enable animation after 1 second. Why not when the scroll bar is released?

Comment: mychecked is not condition of the animation,autoplay.v.mystart is control of the slideshow animation, mychecked is condition of the saviour , if mychecked is false,it wont check, it means it is checking is user still scrolling every one second, on default,.scroll function check every 1 ms , I thought it will save some resources by doing that

Comment: OK, I see now what you are doing. Personally I would use [this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/) which gives jQuery `.scrollstart` and `.scrollstop` events.

Comment: I am not dare to use it if it is a resources hog

Comment: No it's not a resource hog. It's a tidier, generic way to achieve the same as your code (the setTimeout(..., 1000) part). I'm about to post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's a jQuery addon that provides 'scrollstart' and 'scrollstop' events, based on [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/special-scroll-events-for-jquery/), which was written for an early version of jQuery and needed to be modernized.

```
(function($, latency) {
    var special = $.event.special;
    special.scrollstart = {
        setup: function() {
            var timer;
            function handler(evt) {
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                } else {
                    evt.type = 'scrollstart';
                    $.event.handle.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    timer = null;
                }, latency);
            };
            $(this).on('scroll.start', handler);
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $(this).off('scroll.start');
        }
    };
    special.scrollstop = {
        setup: function() {
            var timer;
            function handler(evt) {
                var _self = this,
                    _args = arguments;
                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                }
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    timer = null;
                    evt.type = 'scrollstop';
                    $.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                }, latency);
            };
            $(this).on('scroll.stop', handler);
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $(this).off('scroll.stop');
        }
    };
})(jQuery, 300);
```

This version :

- Replaces `.bind()` and `.unbind()` with `.on()` and `.off()`, plus associated simplification.
- Allows the latency to be specified as a parameter to the self-executing function wrapper.

With 'scrollstart' and 'scrollstop' event detection in place, the application snippet for starting and stopping the animation can be as simple as this :

```
$(window).on ('scrollstart', function(e) {
    allowAnim = false;    
    stopAnim();
}).on ('scrollstop', function(e) {
    allowAnim = true;
    anim();
}).trigger('scrollstop');
```

where `anim()` and `stopAnim()` are your functions for starting and stopping animation(s) and `allowAnim` is a boolean var in an outer scope.

You may want to adjust the latency. I found 300 to be about the minimum acceptable value, and very responsive. Larger A higher value will be less responsive but will better prevent the animation from restarting in mid-scroll.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LqDr4/2/)**

Comment: isn't allowAnim already stopped the animation why do stopAnim() is needed? To change the latency is to change the (jquery,300) ?

Comment: FatDog, I wondered if you would ask about `stopAnim()` - it's inclusion depends on the stop behaviour you want. In my demo, *without* `stopAnim()` the animation queue continues to the end of the current cycle; *with* `stopAnim()`, it stops dead. And yes, to change the latency, edit `(jquery,300)`.

Comment: ohh I never used clearqueue to stop jquery animation thats why i cant stop it immediately, can clearqueue stop an animation by selecting the animation div's parents?

Comment: FatDog, `.clearQueue().stop()` is actually the verbose way to stop immediately. `.stop(true)` has the same effect, see the [API](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). Both forms must be applied to the animated element(s) themselves, not to a container element. Of course, you can always select the animated elements via a common container, eg. `$("#myContainer").find(".myClass").stop(true)`, or similar. I would avoid the `:animated` selector if possible, on efficiency grounds.